# Update stripe connect account's legal entity

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm retrieving a connected account thanks to Stripe PHP library, updating a few information and  trying to save it. But, it throws this error message:

> This account can only be updated with an account token, because it was
>   originally created with an account token. (Attempted to update param
>   'legal_entity' directly.)

Here is my code:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_MYSTRIPESECRETKEY');
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve(ACCOUNT_ID);
$account['legal_entity'] = array('dob' => array('day' => 01,'month' => 01,'year' => 1970));
$account->save();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using the stripe connect for managing account?

Comment: Yes @KathakDabhi

Comment: On stripe connect it is required to create or update an account to have a account token. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account_token

Comment: That's right, I used one when I created the account I'm trying to retrieve. Should I used the same ? And how do you specify this token according to my code ?

Comment: Yes, you should use the same. and have to add the token in request with  account_token param
`$account['account_token'] = $access_token`

Comment: It throws the following message: `Parameter 'legal_entity' cannot be used in conjunction with an account token.`

Comment: Can you post the JSON of the account object. Remove data only available keys under array. As the DOB fields in doc showing at first level but in output it is under legal_entity key.

Comment: It looks like this `{
  "legal_entity": {
    "dob": {
      "day": "26",
      "month": "09",
      "year": "1980"
    }
  },
  "account_token": "ct_token"
}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: creating a token and filling it with the legal entity fields I needed.