# Error when adding account token in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Connect to manage customer accounts. I would like to add tokenized bank account info to an existing account. I use swift to create `account_token` So I do (in python):

```
account = stripe.Account.retrieve(account_id)
account.account_token = account_token
account.save()
```

My error is on `account.save()`. I get the error:

> This account can only be updated with an account token, because it was originally created with an account token.  (Attempted to update param 'account_token' directly.)

How do I avoid this?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609170/stripe-exception-thrown-when-creating-new-connect-account-with-bank-account) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514862/update-stripe-connect-accounts-legal-entity?rq=1), however their solutions did not help this issue.

Comment: Hi there, account_token is not a `bank_account`, if you want to add bank account to a Connected Account, you should make use of the "external_account" attribute. 
where you assign the token to that attribute with account update call. For details, refer to https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-external_account

Comment: Yep, thats right @wsw. Use:
account.external_accounts.create(external_account=account_token)